# how to change animate width property to transform scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, progress-bar, transform

I made a progress bar loading images, so the bar's width animate from 0 to 100%, how can i make the same function with a transform scale property?

This is the actual code:

https://jsfiddle.net/Tibuakaw/db6d3o6h/

```js
updateprogressBar: function() {
        $('#progress-bar').stop().animate({
            'width': (progressBar.loadedElmt / progressBar.countElmt) * 100 + '%'
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('#progress-bar').stop().animate({
   'transform': 'scaleX(' + (progressBar.loadedElmt / progressBar.countElmt) + ')'
});
```

Of cause, you should get the progress bar 100% width in css then